# AzSmb source sode compilation error on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linker-errors

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit

I am download "C++ Source Code Version 2.07" for azsmb at http://members.inode.at/anton.zechner/az/ .

I follow the AzSmb/SmbDemoLinux/Readme.htm instruction to make SmbDemoLinux project.

================
SmbDemo for Linux

Introduction
The SmpDemo is written for the Linux OS. To run the demo you must do following steps:

```
1. Change to the ./SmbDemoLinux/ directory.

2. Compile the demo with make.
...
```

I have the error in below:

> ubuntu@ubuntu-AngHL:~/FluDrive/AzSmb_2.07/AzSmb/SmbDemoLinux$ make
>   make -C ../SmbLibrary make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb_2.07/AzSmb/SmbLibrary' make[1]: Nothing
>   to be done for 'all'. make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb_2.07/AzSmb/SmbLibrary' cc -lstdc++
>   -ldl  -lrt -lpthread SmbDemo.o ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a -o SmbDemo ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a(SystemLinux.o): In function
>   `SysThreadStart':
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SystemLinux.cpp:2574:
>   undefined reference to`pthread_attr_setstacksize'
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SystemLinux.cpp:2575:
>   undefined reference to `pthread_create'
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SystemLinux.cpp:2582:
>   undefined reference to`pthread_detach'
>   ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a(SystemLinux.o): In function
>   `SysSemaphoreCreateEx':
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SystemLinux.cpp:2183:
>   undefined reference to`pthread_condattr_setclock'
>   ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a(SystemLinux.o): In function `SysSleep':
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SystemLinux.cpp:2483:
>   undefined reference to`pthread_condattr_setclock'
>   ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a(SocketUtility.o): In function
>   `SysSleep(unsigned int)':
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SocketUtility.cpp:990:
>   undefined reference to`pthread_condattr_setclock'
>   /home/ubuntu/FluDrive/AzSmb/AzSmb/SmbLibrary/../SmbServer/System/SocketUtility.cpp:1001:
>   undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_setclock' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status Makefile:20: recipe for target 'SmbDemo' failed
>   make: *** [SmbDemo] Error 1

Questions:
1. May I know how to fix the error?

Tried:
1. Include #include  did not help.

```
    File : AzSmb/SmbServer/System/SystemLinux.cpp
```

pthread_attr_init(&iAttr);
        pthread_attr_setstacksize(&iAttr,dwStackSize);  //compile error is here
    if( pthread_create(&iThreadId,&iAttr,SysThreadBegin,pThread))
        {
        free(pThread);
        return 0;
        }

It should pass compilation but now fail.

Comment: I'm sure there's duplicates which is why I comment instead of answer: The problem is that the GNU linker wants libraries listed *after* object files on the command line. For example, if object file `A.o` depend on library `B`, then `A.o` must be listed before `-lB` on the command line, i.e. doing `cc A.o -lB` instead of `cc -lB A.o`. The project you're building uses the wrong order, with the libraries listed before the object files that depend on the libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, can you edit the Makefile to fix it? I need more time to digest it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the makefile needs to be edited, or the script or program creating the makefile. But I suggest you report it as a bug to the project maintainers so they fix it upstream.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have fetch back to  the project maintainers and they will analyze and take action soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cc -lstdc++ -ldl -lrt -lpthread SmbDemo.o ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a -o SmbDemo
> ```

Libraries need to be listed last. You must fix the makefile to use the command line like:

```
cc -o SmbDemo SmbDemo.o ../SmbLibrary/SmbServer.a -lstdc++ -ldl -lrt -lpthread
```

Also, you should *not* be adding the `-lstdc++` manually. Instead you should use the C++ compiler (`CC`, not `cc`), and the C++ compiler will add it for you.

Also see [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/608639)

Comment: Hi @iww, it work. Thank you very much.